# rails will create rollback in transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, radix

with Rails 4, inside a transaction, when transaction was rollbacked because of some error,
Will record inerted to db with create be rollbacked ?

e.g.

```
User.transaction do
  @users.each do |user|
    User.create(user)
  end
end
```

Comment: yes if you look in the logs (log/development.log) you will see `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` sql being issued around sql blocks - try putting `raise "TEST"` after `User.create(user)` in your example you should end up with `ROLLBACK` issued via sql

Answer (score 0):

Yes look up more on your database servers doc on transactions:
MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html.

PostgreSQL
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html